# R lavaan sem categorical variable no standard error

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I want to compute a structural equation model with the `sem()` function in `R` with the package `lavaan`.

There are two categorial variables, one latent exogenous and one latent endogenous, I want to include in the final version of the model.

When I include one of the categorial variables in the model, however, `R` produces the following warning:

> 1: In estimateVCOV(lavaanModel, samplestats = lavaanSampleStats,
>   options = lavaanOptions,  :   lavaan WARNING: could not compute
>   standard errors!
>
> 2: In computeTestStatistic(lavaanModel, partable = lavaanParTable,  : 
>   lavaan WARNING: could not compute scaled test statistic

## Code used:

```
model1 <- '

Wertschaetzung_Essen =~ abwechslungsreiche_M + schnell_zubereitbar + koche_sehr_gerne + koche_sehr_haeufig

Fleischverzicht =~ Ern_Index1

Fleischverzicht ~ Wertschaetzung_Essen
'

fit_model1 <- sem(model1, data=survey2_subset, ordered = c("Ern_Index1"))
```

*Note:* This is only a small version of the final model and in which I only introduce one categorial variable. The warning, however, is the same for more complex versions of the model.

## Output

```
 str(survey2_subset):


   'data.frame':    3676 obs. of  116 variables:
 $ abwechslungsreiche_M : num  4 2 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 3 ...
 $ schnell_zubereitbar  : num  0 3 2 0 0 1 3 2 1 1 ...
 $ koche_sehr_gerne     : num  1 3 3 1 3 1 4 4 4 3 ...
 $ koche_sehr_haeufig   : num  2 2 3 NA 3 2 2 4 3 3 ...
 $ Ern_Index1           : num  1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...


 summary(fit_model1, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized=TRUE)

    lavaan (0.5-15) converged normally after  31 iterations

                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                          3469        3676

  Estimator                                       DWLS      Robust
  Minimum Function Test Statistic               13.716          NA
  Degrees of freedom                                 4           4
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.008          NA
  Scaling correction factor                                     NA
  Shift parameter                                     
    for simple second-order correction (Mplus variant)

        Model test baseline model:

  Minimum Function Test Statistic             2176.159    1582.139
  Degrees of freedom                                10          10
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000

       User model versus baseline model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.996          NA
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.989          NA

      Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.026          NA
  90 Percent Confidence Interval          0.012  0.042          NA     NA
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.994          NA

   Parameter estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Standard Errors                           Robust.sem

          Estimate  Std.err  Z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  Latent variables:
  Wertschaetzung_Essen =~
    abwchslngsr_M     1.000                               0.363    0.436
    schnll_zbrtbr     1.179                               0.428    0.438
    koche_shr_grn     2.549                               0.925    0.846
    koche_shr_hfg     2.530                               0.918    0.775
  Fleischverzicht =~
    Ern_Index1        1.000                               0.249    0.249

Regressions:
  Fleischverzicht ~
    Wrtschtzng_Es     0.302                               0.440    0.440

Intercepts:
    abwchslngsr_M     3.133                               3.133    3.760
    schnll_zbrtbr     1.701                               1.701    1.741
    koche_shr_grn     2.978                               2.978    2.725
    koche_shr_hfg     2.543                               2.543    2.148
    Wrtschtzng_Es     0.000                               0.000    0.000
    Fleischvrzcht     0.000                               0.000    0.000

Thresholds:
    Ern_Index1|t1     0.197                               0.197    0.197

Variances:
    abwchslngsr_M     0.562                               0.562    0.810
    schnll_zbrtbr     0.771                               0.771    0.808
    koche_shr_grn     0.339                               0.339    0.284
    koche_shr_hfg     0.559                               0.559    0.399
    Ern_Index1        0.938                               0.938    0.938
    Wrtschtzng_Es     0.132                               1.000    1.000
    Fleischvrzcht     0.050                               0.806    0.806
```

Is the model not identified? There should be enough degrees of freedom and the loadings of the first manifest items are set to one.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: at the very least you need to provide the output of `str(survey2_subset)`

Comment: and I would imagine that there is a `summary` function for such objects, night wahr?

Comment: Hi BondedDust, I had problems with formatting...

Comment: I hope that the information provided now is sufficient and allows one to help me

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was:

You can´t have missing values in the dataframe, because with categorial variables WLSMV is used and FIML (missing="ML") is only usable with ML estimates. Perhaps that´s a problem.

Also: Does `lavaan` automatically fix the residual-variance of "Fleischverzicht" to 0 (or some other value)? A single-item latent variable would not be identified without that, I think.